# Batch file to clear CSC

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

Need help with a batch file to clear CSC.

I found a way how to by

`REG ADD "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\CSC\Parameters" /v FormatDatabase /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f`

Is there way to way to do this with batch file for Windows 7?

Comment: Just put that command inside the batch file. Where are you getting stuck exactly?

Comment: When start the bat file erreur ( can't find)

Comment: The raison for the have user using windows 7 get slow when try to open the session work.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and specify _can't find_: can't find **what**? (copy&paste from your `cmd` window).

Comment: Hello there Way to start that bat file :

Comment: REG ADD "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\CSC\Parameters" /v FormatDatabase /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f

Comment: I look if there way to start that bat file remotly

Answer (score 0):

You should put the same command in a batch file, and it should work correctly (Not tried it myself, and it added the registry key.)

You just have to make sure to execute the batch file as administrator (Right click>Run As Administrator), since you need admin rights to add a registry key.